# How do I upload document by converting HttpClient request to RestSharp request?

Tags: c#, postman, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient, restsharp

After i logged in to API i used, I am trying to upload a document with using RestSharp.

I was able to do this using Postman. Screenshot is given below:

[image: Postman successful request.]

Postman code generator generates this code block for me:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://80.211.238.187/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/17.200.001/StockItem/POSTMAN123/files/sample.pdf");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
request.AddParameter("application/pdf", "<file contents here>", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

but idk how to edit the <**file contents here**> part from given code block above.

I was also able to achieve it using the HttpClient suggested in the respective API's documentation guide:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\fcomak\Downloads\sample.pdf"))
{
    _httpClient.PutAsync("http://80.211.238.187/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/17.200.001/StockItem/POSTMAN123/files/sample.pdf", new StreamContent(sr.BaseStream))
        .Result
        .EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

But i need to convert HttpClient request to RestSharp request. I tried to achieve this using RestSharp, but failed. Even if I could send the file, its content was not browse correctly. Here is the code block i tried:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\fcomak\Downloads\sample.pdf"))
{
    restClient.Execute(new RestRequest("http://80.211.238.187/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/17.200.001/StockItem/POSTMAN123/files/sample.pdf", Method.PUT)
        .AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
        .AddParameter("application/pdf", new StreamContent(sr.BaseStream), ParameterType.RequestBody));
}
```

I can sending or getting json contents by using this api with this **restClient** by the way. And of course i logged in already. The reason for my failure is about my restClient.
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: it's probably about `new StreamContent(sr.BaseStream)` part.

Comment: And when i open the uploaded pdf file by restClient with notepad, it gives me this text:
`System.Net.Http.StreamContent`

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] value = wc.DownloadData("http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf");
    restClient.Execute(new RestRequest("http://80.211.238.187/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/17.200.001/StockItem/POSTMAN123/files/sample.pdf", Method.PUT)
        .AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
        .AddParameter("application/pdf", value, ParameterType.RequestBody)
        );
}
```

As you see, i used `WebClient.DownloadData()` instead of `StreamReader.BaseStream()`

Or, you can convert you local data to **byte** array with `File.ReadAllBytes()`

```
string entitySource = @"C:\Users\fcomak\Downloads\sample2.pdf";
byte[] value = File.ReadAllBytes(entitySource);
restClient.Execute(new RestRequest(entityBasePath + entityName + "/" + inventoryID + "/files/" + fileName, Method.PUT)
        .AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
        .AddParameter("application/pdf", value, ParameterType.RequestBody)
        );
```

FYI